# Which one should I install? Ubuntu 18 or Ubunto 19.04?

Tags: 18.04, 19.04

For some reasons, I had to install Ubuntu 19.04 over 18.04 knowing that it lacks LTS. I want to know could I upgrade my system to the next stable version when it was released? if yes, then I think I wouldn't loose much! right?

Comment: Ubuntu only allows upgrade to the immediately next version with one exception. The exception is for Long Term Support (LTS) versions.

Comment: I would recommend either 19.10 ([yes, it's out](https://ubuntu.com/)) or 18.04, depending on how you want to balance new features vs. stability. Both will be able to upgrade directly to 20.04 LTS when it comes out next spring.